# Disk utility won't let me use the restore option to get a .dmg image onto a USB

Tags: mac, usb, disk-utility, unix, dmg

I'm tying to make a bootable Debian USB drive. All I need to do is restore the USB drive from the Debian dmg. I get this error. The debian.org documentation is not helpful with this specific issue. Here's what I keep running into.

[image]

Comment: How was the image created and explicitly from what source?

Comment: I downloaded the ISO, formatted the USB to OS X Extended Journaled, and in terminal i used 'hdutil convert -format UDRW -o destination.dmg source.iso' (this is the template of the command) to make the disk image.

Comment: This method worked fine with Ubuntu, but I must be skipping a step. I had a little bit of luck using Ubuntu to download the debian.iso file, then making a bootable disk on a FAT format, but the boot-loader does not work on a mac. The disk is bootable only on a windows computer. Footnote: Unetbootin does not work with Debian, for some reason.

Comment: What was the original name of the Debian ISO Image?  Have you tried just using `dd` to write the original ISO Image to the USB drive?

Comment: hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o /Volumes/debian/debian.img /Users/Jacob/Desktop/debian-8.2.0-amd64-DVD-3.iso

Comment: I just used this to try and write it directly to the USB drive instead of using the restore command. But I don't think it will be bootable, unless reFind will work as a boot loader? I have reFind because I already dual-boot ubuntu, but I'm trying to replace Ubuntu with debian, for stability reasons.

Comment: First of all the `debian-8.2.0-amd64-DVD-3.iso` image is not a bootable image and secondly there is no need to do any conversion, simply use `dd` to directly write the **debian-8.2.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso** image to the USB Flash Drive.

Comment: I understand that. I have already tried using an ISO with EFI boot loader on the USB, and it showed up in reFind, but when I tried to use it, I just got a black screen with the flashing cursor. It doesn't work, that's why I'm trying to use a .dmg, which worked when I installed Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `dd`, from the command line (Terminal).

The syntax is as follows:

`sudo dd if=/path/to/file/<file> of=/dev/disk<your drive number> bs=1m`

It will prompt you for your password, and you will not be able to see it as you type.

To get your disk number, you can run `diskutil list` from Terminal, and find the disk that most closely matches your drive's stats.